# join the contents of files into a new file

Tags: awk

I have some text files as shown below. I would like to join the contents of these  files into one.

file A

```
>AXC
145
146
147
>SDF
1
8
67
>FGH
```

file B

```
>AXC
>SDF
 12
 65
>FGH
 123
 156
 190
```

Desired ouput

new file

```
>AXC
145
146
147
>SDF
 1
 8
 67
 12
 65
>FGH
 123
 156
 190
```

your help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '
    /^>/ { key=$0; if (!seen[key]++) keys[++numKeys] = key; next }
    { vals[key] = vals[key] ORS $0 }
    END{ for (keyNr=1;keyNr<=numKeys;keyNr++) {key = keys[keyNr]; print key vals[key]} }
' fileA fileB
>AXC
145
146
147
>SDF
1
8
67
 12
 65
>FGH
 123
 156
 190
```

If you really want the leading white space added to the ">SDF" values from fileA, tell us why that's the case for that one but not ">AXC" so we can code an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter than Ed's answer

```
awk '/^>/{a=$0;next}{x[a]=x[a]$0"\n"}END{for(i in x)printf"%s\n%s",i,x[i]}'
```

Blocks will be printed in an unspecified order.

Answer (score 0):

- `RS=">"` seperate records by `>` character
- `OFS="\n"` is to have number it's own line.
- `a[i]=a[i] $0` add fields into array with index of first field.
- `rt=RT` is for adding `>` character to index

---

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ RS=">"; OFS="\n" } 
    {i=rt $1; $1=""; a[i]=a[i] $0; rt=RT; next} 
    END { for (i in a) {print i a[i] }}' d6 d5

>SDF
12
65
1
8
67
>FGH
123
156
190
>AXC
145
146
147
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Code-only answers are less useful for future readers and don’t explain the OP’s mistake or how to approach the problem.